# cat into stdin then pipe into program keeps forked shell open, why?

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, input

I'm not sure what's going on but I've been trying to understand what is happening with the input and output. So here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    char pass[8];
    fgets(pass, 8, stdin);
    if (pass[1] == 'h'){
        printf("enter shell\n");
        system("/bin/bash");
        printf("leave shell\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here are some terminal commands. When I run it regularly, and input 'hh', the shell stays opened.

```
idkanything ~ $ ./a.out
hh
enter shell
bash-3.2$
```

Now I try to echo then pipe, but the shell closes immediately.

```
idkanything ~ $ echo "hh" | ./a.out
enter shell
leave shell
```

So now here is when it works:

```
idkanything ~ $ cat <(python -c 'print "hh"') - | ./a.out
enter shell
this work
/bin/bash: line 1: this: command not found
leave shell
```

But when I leave out the '-' for stdin, it does not work as in the shell closes immediately.

```
idkanything ~ $ cat <(python -c 'print "hh"') | ./a.out
enter shell
leave shell
```

When I have cat at the end here, it also works.

```
idkanything ~ $ (python -c 'print "hh"'; cat) | ./a.out
enter shell
this works
/bin/bash: line 1: this: command not found
leave shell
```

Can someone please explain what's going on? What specifically about the commands that work makes the shell stay open? Why does the shell only stay open for these commands and not for the other commands like echoing "hh" and then piping that in.

I believe it may have something to do with stdout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the cases where it "works", you are leaving a process running **`cat`** which is reading *its* standard input, which has not been closed.  Since that is not (yet) closed, **`cat`** continues to run, leaving *its* standard output open, which is used by the shell (also not closed).

Comment: But what is the meaning of this:cat <(python -c 'print "hh"') - | ./a.out command or (python -c 'print "hh"'; cat) | ./a.out? Like how is cat being left open in here and not in the others?

Comment: cat is on the end - still running.  From another terminal, do "ps -efl" to see what is there.